# simple-image-reducer does not start / ImportError: No module named Image

Tags: python

Problem:

```
~$ simple-image-reducer

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/simple-image-reducer", line 28, in <module>
    import Image

ImportError: No module named Image
```

Reason:

Image != image

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2):

It is a [bug 1825832](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-image-reducer/+bug/1825832).

Please login to launchpad and click "*This bug affects you and 1 other person*" to confirm that this bug affects you.

The solution from proposed patch is simple - use PIL instead of Image.
We can apply the [patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/420535183/patch) programmatically without installing other stuff:

```
sudo sed -i "s/^import Image/from PIL import Image/" /usr/bin/simple-image-reducer
```

Answer (score 1):

1) make sure it is available

```
python -m pip install  Image
```

2) where is it available?

```
sudo find ~ -name image -type d
```

-->> directory /home/MyHomeDir/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/image
->> OK

3)  Tell simple-image-reducer via link:

```
ln -s ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/image ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Image
```

4)
invoke `simple-image-reducer`  again.

Works:-)

Rem: Ubuntu 19.10, 19.04

Comment: the solution from n0rbert https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert is more generic and applies to all users. As long as it works it may be preferrable. As long as there is no new installation of old simple-image-reducer code making it void. However, the issue seems to be related to the upper / lower case writing of "Image" vs "image". This might happen again (simple-image-reducer is not maintained while python is progressing).